# java parser file text

Tags: java, mysql, parsing

i have this text file and i wanna parser and put it into mysql database:

```
    A:PE9301_P# show port 1/1/1 
===============================================================================
Ethernet Interface
===============================================================================
Description        : PE9301_P:PE9148_P:01:10G
Interface          : 1/1/1                      Oper Speed       : 10 Gbps
Link-level         : Ethernet                   Config Speed     : N/A
Admin State        : up                         Oper Duplex      : full
Oper State         : up - Active in LAG 1       Config Duplex    : N/A
Physical Link      : Yes                        MTU              : 9212
Single Fiber Mode  : No                         Min Frame Length : 64 Bytes
```

and i want just those info:
PE9301,up - Active in LAG 1
i can't find a solution help mz plz

Comment: Could you at least show us what table structure you want?  I think the full answer to your question is a bit too broad.

Comment: Looks like extensive use of `String.split` and maybe some regex.

Comment: i didn't create my table yet i'm searching how i can parser without separtor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regexp:

```
/Description\s+:\s([\w\s]+)/g
```

and

```
/Oper State\s+:\s(.{26,26})/g
```

If you want to parse the whole structure, use character length rather than regular expressions to split the structure into key-value array, and compare keys to constants ("Description", "Oper State", etc...)

A working exemple as a Java test unit :

```
private static final String NIFSOURCE = "A:PE9301_P# show port 1/1/1\r\n"+
        "===============================================================================\r\n"+
        "Ethernet Interface\r\n"+
        "===============================================================================\r\n"+
        "Description        : PE9301_P:PE9148_P:01:10G\r\n"+
        "Interface          : 1/1/1                      Oper Speed       : 10 Gbps\r\n"+
        "Link-level         : Ethernet                   Config Speed     : N/A\r\n"+
        "Admin State        : up                         Oper Duplex      : full\r\n"+
        "Oper State         : up - Active in LAG 1       Config Duplex    : N/A\r\n"+
        "Physical Link      : Yes                        MTU              : 9212\r\n"+
        "Single Fiber Mode  : No                         Min Frame Length : 64 Bytes";

/**
 * Ceci est un test que l'ont peut remplacer par une méthode Main ou une function 
 *                                                             - Uncle Bob Martin
 */
@Test
public void NIFParseTest() {
    String NIFdescription = null, NIFstate = null;

    Pattern motifRE = Pattern.compile("^Description\\s+:\\s(\\w+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Pattern stateRE = Pattern.compile("^Oper State\\s+:\\s(.{26,26})", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.UNIX_LINES);

    Matcher foundMatch = motifRE.matcher(NIFSOURCE);
    if (foundMatch.find()) {
        NIFdescription = foundMatch.group(1); //0 est la chaine complète, les motifs entre parenthèse sont disponibles à l'index 1
    }

    foundMatch = stateRE.matcher(NIFSOURCE);
    if (foundMatch.find()) {
        NIFstate = foundMatch.group(1);
    }
    assertNotNull(NIFdescription);
    assertNotNull(NIFstate);
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand your answer can u make for me an exemple plz

Comment: I just did it for you